# Camel CXF on context startup

Tags: apache-camel, cxf

We're migrating our suits of applications from Camel 2 to Camel 4, I'm encountering several problem during the migration (as I expected) especially when we had to use the latest Wildlfy release and with that give up on the Wildfly Camel Patch.

I managed to start the routes, but I'm encountering this exception that I can't figure out how to solve:

> Failed to start route route3 because of Cannot cast
> org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl to
> org.apache.cxf.wsdl.WSDLManager

I'm using the following pom:

```
<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
                <artifactId>wildfly-parent</artifactId>
                <version>29.0.1</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.enterprise</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.enterprise.cdi-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>10.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.10.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.annotation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-jms</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-attachments</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-activemq</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-cxf-soap</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>
```

Comment: Check your classpath (+ dependencies). You probably have duplicated versions of CXF jar's